# Confuse in how to post data for edit row in jqgrid

Tags: php, mysql, jqgrid, server-side

This is the first time I'm using jqgrid.
I have confused in how to post all value from modal's edit row(pencil icon).

I'm so familiar with dataTable but not in this plugin. I need some server side script for this edit process. So, I can learn from it.

Could you give some tutorials or sample to send this data?

thanks in advance.

---

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
                         url:'dounfinish.php',
                         datatype: 'json',
                         mtype: 'POST',
                         colNames:['id','Date', 'Line','Shift','Model','Serial','DIC','Def_class','Symptom','Cause','Symgrup','Modgrup'],
                         colModel :[......],
                         pager: jQuery('#pager'),
                         rowNum:10,
                         rowList:[10,20,30],
                         sortname: 'Problem_date',
                         sortorder: "desc",
                         editurl: "process1.php",
                                                viewrecords: true,
                                                imgpath: 'themes/basic/images',
                                                caption: 'OQC DEFECT DATA'
                                                }); 
                        jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{edit:true,add:false,del:false});
```

how to send data to this:

```
........
case 'edit':
         edit(postVar('id'),postVar('DIC'),postVar('Def_class'),postVar('Symptom'),postVar('Cause'));
                break;
           });
function edit($id,$DIC,$Def_class,$Symptom,$Cause){
        $defID = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
        $DIC = mysql_real_escape_string($DIC);
        $Defclass = mysql_real_escape_string($Def_class);
        $Symp = mysql_real_escape_string($Symptom);
        $Cause = mysql_real_escape_string($Cause);
        $DIC=strtoupper($DIC);
        $Defclass=strtoupper($Defclass);

        $sql = "UPDATE oqc_defect SET DIC = '".$DIC."', Def_class = '".$Defclass."', ";
        $sql.= "Symptom = '".$Symp."', Cause = '".$Cause."' ";
        $sql.= "WHERE def_id = ".$defID;

echo $sql;
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(_ERROR26.": ".mysql_error());
//echo $result;
mysql_close($dbc);
}
```

Comment: is add functionality working??? or the problem is with both add and edit functionalities???

Comment: actually,I dont know how jqgrid work because for the first time I'm using dataTable. I don't how to pass this value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add `loadonce : true` all can work normally.